# Post array From android to Php and searching from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am `Post`ing From Android to PHP

```
Cityid is an Arraylist of Interger
 jo.put("cityid",cityid);
```

How can I post this in PHP, search record from an array in the table, and convert into JSON encoding

```
$ids=$_POST['areaids[]'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM subcategory where categoryid in (' . implode(",", $ids) . ')";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($result)
{
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $data[]=$row;
  }

  print(json_encode($data));
}
```

Receiving back JsonData in Android

```
JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
            JSONObject jo=null;

            categorys.clear();
            Area category;

            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                category=new Area();
                category.setStateid(jo.getInt("state"));
                category.setCityid(jo.getInt("city"));
                category.setAreaid(jo.getInt("id"));
                category.setAreaname(jo.getString("area"));
                category.setPincode(jo.getInt("pincode"));
                categorys.add(category);
            }
```

Comment: i didn't get you what exactly you want to do what i can understand so far is that you want to send an array from android and get that array in php and search that data in database please let me know if i am correct

Comment: yes exactly correct

Comment: it should be a simple array or json will work??

Comment: I am posting ArrayList<Integer> ids;

Comment: and Need Json_encode that in output

Comment: please post the code where you are sending the data

Comment: Check i have posted

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$val=file_get_contents('php://input'); 

//this where you are getting the data which is coming as input in post from android
```

and after that `$val` will be your array and you can get data from that

like this:

```
$val->your key fordata
```

Comment: I dont know much about php i didnt get your point and what about search data from databse means sql query

Comment: are you able to get data into php which is you are sending from android

Comment: no i am not able to get data in php android code is ok

Comment: $ids=$_POST['areaids[]'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM subcategory where categoryid in (' . implode(",", $ids) . ')";

Comment: problem may in this two above statement only

Comment: then the code in my answer is to get the data which is you are sending data from android  and `$val` will be your array you just need to replace  `$_POST['areaids[]'];` with `file_get_contents('php://input');` then you will be able to get the data

Comment: and what about sql query from $val how to write that